# How to run external program in graphical mode

Tags: linux, external-calls

I can run system command from Mathematica with `Run["command"]`. But if the `command` starts windowed application then nothing happens.

For example `Run["gnome-terminal"]` does nothing.

How can I run external applications in graphical mode from Mathematica?

---

When I run `RunProcess["gnome-terminal"]` I get an error

```
<|"ExitCode" -> 127,
  "StandardOutput" -> "", 
  "StandardError" -> "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0: undefined symbol: g_type_class_adjust_private_offset"
 |>
```

I looked at the library `libatspi.so.0`:

```
$ nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0 | grep g_type_class

U g_type_class_adjust_private_offset
U g_type_class_peek_parent
U g_type_class_ref
```

So the symbol is defined in the library so I have no idea what is Mathematica complaining about.

---

I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04.

I tested few other applications other then `gnome-terminal` and some of them works and some of them don't..strange.

Applications that does not work

```
gnome-terminal, emacs, nautilus
```

Applications that work

```
Mathematica, xterm, emacs-24.5
```

Okay, it has to do something with graphical interfaces. The difference between emacs and emacs-24.5 is that it has a different GUI. Maybe one is using GTK and the other is not, I do not know.

Comment: It works for me. What value is returned by `Run` ?  Try this: `RunProcess[{"which","gnome-terminal"}]`

Comment: @george2079 Output is `<|"ExitCode" -> 0, "StandardOutput" -> "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal ", "StandardError" -> ""|>`

Comment: And `Run["gnome-terminal"]` returns `32512`

Comment: hmm.. the `32512` is an error (should be `0`).  Maybe `RunProcess["gnome-terminal"]` will show the error.

Comment: The error is `<|"ExitCode" -> 127, "StandardOutput" -> "", 
 "StandardError" -> 
  "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal: symbol lookup error: \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0: undefined symbol: \
g_type_class_adjust_private_offset
  "|>`

Comment: On a Mac, `Run["open -a <your_app_here>"]` works, but without `open`, it fails.  Obviously this is system dependent.  I guess you're probably using Linux, given one of the path names.  You don't really say explicitly though.  I don't know, but I wonder if the version of Linux matters, too.  Linux may have something equivalent to the OSX `open` command.  What happens if you run `gnome-terminal` from the command line? Maybe it has nothing to do with *Mathematica*.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for idea, running `gnome-terminal` from command line works fine but I tried running different applications from Mathematica and some of them works and some don't. See edited question for more info.

Comment: Try `Run["LD_LIBRARY_PATH= command"]`.

Comment: @ilian solution `Run["LD_LIBRARY_PATH= command"]` works for me